# TensorFlow lite speech recognition with custom dataset is not working

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, speech-recognition, tensorflow-lite

I am using the TensorFlow lite example which they are given for speech recognition [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/speech_commands/android). I want to use my own custom dataset and train the model and use it in there example, but when i am training my custom dataset with there python scripts [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/speech_commands/train.py) it gives error. I have change the python script with custom parameter for dataset path and all and run the script, but it gives following error :

[image]

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 513, in <module>
    tf.compat.v1.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 299, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 250, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "train.py", line 235, in main
    train_fingerprints, train_ground_truth = audio_processor.get_data(
  File "/Users/pleximus/Documents/Projects/TensorFlow/Project1/new/speech_commands/input_data.py", line 575, in get_data
    background_index = np.random.randint(len(self.background_data))
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 743, in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.randint
  File "_bounded_integers.pyx", line 1260, in numpy.random._bounded_integers._rand_int64
ValueError: low >= high
```

My custom dataset link [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S4_bbE0kgt-98HrOTM1BY-et58esZYVq/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 1):

Try to adjust the bitrate. Use `ffmpeg -i <file>` to obtain the bitrate of your wave files. Then, when execute the training script, use the `--sample_rate` parameter.

For example my files have a sample rate of 44 kHz, then I use:

```
python tensorflow/examples/speech_commands/train.py --data_url= --data_dir=/tmp/speech_dataset/ --wanted_words=ok,test,mycommand --sample_rate=44000
```